# Using Terminal, Launch VSCode into a project folder and open a project file

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, terminal, subprocess

I am writing a Python Script and I want to use `subprocess` - basically MacOS `terminal` (Flavor probably not important) to launch `VSCode` (installed) into a project directory e.g. `~/workspace/my/project/` and have it open a file within that folder e.g. `~/workspace/my/project/javascript-file.js`. How can I achieve this?

This is a self answered entry for clarification of others who may be looking for similar solutions when writing Python Scripts as local development tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode editor is opened using the `code` executable in MacOS `Terminal`, and thus can be used the same way when running `python` code.

The `code` executable enables you to pass several arguments (specifying paths to 'open' once the editor launches)

```py
try:
    # This will raise if code does not exist on the machine
    subprocess.run(['code', '-r', '/workspace/folder', f'/workspace/folder/file.js'], check=True, text=True)
except:
    print(f'Failed to launch VSCode')
```

Comment: You can accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.